# Google Glass and RTSP

Tags: rtsp, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am not to sure how to format this question. Here it is:

How exactly does RTSP work? More specifically, how does Google Glass and the MirrorAPI implement it? Does Mirror provide as the "middle ground" between both clients? Or does the protocol connect both clients without the middle ground? I ask this because I know that the timeline is associated with a Gmail account thus requiring access to a Google server. Also, since Glass is card based, does the protocol render a card on the users timeline because if so that would require Mirror to act as a middle ground.

Any leads would be great, Thank you

**Update**

Has anyone tried to implement RTSP and Glass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mirror API does indeed stand between Glassware that use it and Glass hardware. You can learn more about the place of the Mirror API on the [stories](https://developers.google.com/glass/stories) page in the docs, but RTSP is not part of the Mirror API.

Comment: Thank you Jenny. Do you know how this is seen on Glass? I need to read more on RTSP.